# Mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, mapping, data-types

Mapping do not have a length, nor do they have the concept of key or a values being set.

Is this statement True or False?

Please provide the explanation also.

The solidity docs say “Mappings can be seen as hash tables which are virtually initialized such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros

Answer (score 2):

`True`, why because we do have the concept of **keys** and **values** in mappings **but they are not really being set inside the mapping**, only its `keccak256` hash is used to look up the value.

---

Why they use `keccak256` hash instead of actual value in mappings (As per [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/security-considerations.html#minor-details)) :

Types that do not occupy the full 32 bytes might contain “dirty higher order bits”. This is especially important if you access `msg.data` - it poses a malleability risk: You can craft transactions that call a function `f(uint8 x)` with a raw byte argument of `0xff000001` and with `0x00000001`. Both are fed to the contract and both will look like the number `1` as far as `x` is concerned, but msg.data will be different, so if you use `keccak256(msg.data)` for anything, you will get different results.

---

If you want to read out some more info and want to understand how it works internally, you should try reading -> [**How you can clear Mappings ?**](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/security-considerations.html#clearing-mappings)

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the example you mention? When I try to pass in `0xff000001` to a `uint8` param I get the error `Error encoding arguments: Error: value out-of-bounds (argument=null, value="0xff000001", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)`. This was in Remix.